# Query if array column contains one or more values or not

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an PropertyPromotion model which has an attribute called as platform whose values are array data type. I need to query all the PropertyPromotion whose platform attribute has values that are present in some particular array.

For Example: I have an array

```
platform = ["android"]
```

the `PropertyPromotion.platform` may have values as ["android", "iphone"]

I need to return all PropertyPromotion that might have either "android" or "iphone" as one of their platform array values

I tried the following:

```
PropertyPromotion.where("platform @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", platform)
PropertyPromotion.where("platform && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", platform)
PropertyPromotion.where('platform @> ARRAY[?]::integer[]', platform)
```

But I got below syntax error :-

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@> ARRAY['android']::integer[])' at line 1: SELECT `property_promotions`.* FROM `property_promotions` WHERE (platform @> ARRAY['android']::integer[])
```

My mysql version is mysql  `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

And I also can't change the version because it is an existing project.

Any Solutions??

Comment: I'm not sure if it works with array data_types but try: 
PropertyPromotion.where(platform: ['android', 'iphone'])

Comment: Mysql don't have native support for storing arrays, you should serialize it as `json` for example. Syntax you tried corresponds to Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

if `platform = ["android"]`  is an array of strings you can use

```
PropertyPromotion.where('platform in (#{platform_arr})')
```

where platform_arr is an array containg the values you want to get 
ex. `platform_arr = ['android','ios']`

Comment: Not worked same error :-  **Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["android", "iphone"]))' at line 1: SELECT `property_promotions`.* FROM `property_promotions` WHERE (platform IN (["android", "iphone"]))**

Comment: Try `PropertyPromotion.where('platform in (#{platform_arr.map(&:inspect).join(', ')})')`

Comment: @HishamMagdy string interpolation works only with double quotes `PropertyPromotion.where("platform in (#{platform_arr})")`